# How to improve this code for finding the k largest elements of an array?

Tags: algorithm, performance, priority-queue, binary-heap, heapq

The following code to find the k largest elements of an array is causing a TLE error. How can I optimize it to make it run faster?

```
import heapq    
for _ in range(int(input())):         
    n,k=map(int,input().split())   
    lists=list(map(int,input().split()))  
    
    heapq.heapify(lists)       
    
    for i in range(k+1):
        klargest=heapq.nlargest(i,lists)  
    
    print(*klargest)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! From what you've posted here, I don't understand what your question is. Can you edit your question to elaborate more on what you're unsure about? Thanks!

Comment: actually it is showing TLE error that is what I'm asking how to optimise this. This is the question to print the k-largest elements of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(k+1):
   klargest=heapq.nlargest(i,lists)
```

The time complexity of each klargest operation is O(k*log n)) where n is the number of elements in heap.
In the above code snippet, this operation is running for k+1 times for the values [0,k].

Calculating the time for the loop:

**iteration value**               (Time)

i == 0                       (0*log(n))

i == 1                       (1*log(n))

i == 2                       (2*log(n))

....

i == k-1                     ((k-1)*log(n))

i == k                       ((k)*log(n))

Total time will be the sum of time taken in each operation = (0.log(n)) + (1*log(n)) + .... + ((k-1)*log(n)) + ((k)*log(n))

Total time = (0+1+2...+(k-1)+k)*log(n)
= ((k*(k+1))/2)*log(n)

> ***Total time*** ~~ O(k^2*(log(n)))
>
> That's why the above code results in TLE.

**OPTIMISED APPROACH:**

```
import heapq    
for _ in range(int(input())):         
    n,k=map(int,input().split())   
    lists=list(map(int,input().split()))  
    
    heapq.heapify(lists)       
    
    for i in range(n-k):
        heapq.heappop(lists)
    klargest = list(lists) # converting heap to list
    print(*klargest)
```

As Inbuilt heap in python is min-heap. So the above code is popping out minimum n-k elements from lists. Popping out each operation will take log(n) time. Thus total time will be ~~ (n-k)*logn.
The remaining k elements in the heap are the klargest elements that we want to find.

Thus, the time complexity for the above solution is O((n-k)*log(n)) == **O(nlog(n))** which is a optimised time complexity.